# Blackberry PIN verification

Tags: blackberry, verification

Do BlackBerry phones have any PIN-number verification function, similar to credit cards, which use last digit (a.k.a. check digit) for verification?

I am doing some order processing on my site, and users have to enter their BlackBerry PIN. Of course, once in a while they type it wrong. If there was some known verification function I would be able to spot this right away and ask the user to correct it.

Comment: A  native application would be better suited for this, since you can extract this data from the device without the user typing it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try checking the pin that user input was in hex

Comment: Sure, but users still can type '8' instead of 'B', or 'D' as '0' - this is why a check function would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

website using javascript could do check like this

var hex=/^[0-9a-fA-F]*$/;
 if (hex.test(pin)==false) {
do what u want with it
}

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I know how to check for a hex number. The thing is, the number itself can be entered wrong. For example instead of 1234ABCD user can enter 1234A8C0. It's a valid hex number, but it's not his PIN. To make sure your credit card number is entered correctly, for example, credit cards use 'check digit' (Google it). I am wondering if there's something similar with BB PINs.